# Hint parallelization for U-SQL outputter

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have a custom u-sql outputter which has some reasonably heavy lifting to do.

My understanding is that an outputter will naturally parallelize and create separate files, as stitching the files back together in Azure Data Lake Store is a quick operation.

Running as either a custom outputter or processor (with a CSV outputter) I only ever see one vertex being run.

Is there a way to hint to multiple vertices?